# # in URL SAP Gateway SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

In SAP gateway and SAPUI5, When we has Filter parameter like projectid = "TEST Project #123".

When the request comes to backend service, getting projectid = "TEST Project only not anything after #.

can anyone help to resolve this.

Comment: Hash has special meaning in a url. Can you url encode the hash? It would translate to `%23`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am encoding encodeURIComponent() and sending the url.. Its working now